# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: 2010, development

I am fetching data from external list using SPListItemCollection.GetDataTable() method. But this method throws error:

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store
>   <2015-03-24 13:51:51:007> in MyDate Column. Expected type is DateTime.

I searched in the forum i found [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/461c9f36-a7a0-4048-9343-02b7bd498a29/error-when-fetching-data-from-external-list?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

I tried it, but no luck! Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the DataType of MyDate Column?

Comment: CHECK THIS https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/714d05bc-e1ce-4a49-b180-664bc63cbe05/error-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetimecouldnt-store?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Answer (score 2):

the date format is typically the [ISO format 8601](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx) `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ`

(the above page documentation is actually wrong as it states minutes twice)

e.g.

```
(get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ")
```

output

```
2017-10-11T11:56:53Z
```